# Pandas: Add new column and assigning value from another dataframe by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have two dataframes DF1 and DF2

**DF1:**

```
id      product
a       a
b       b
c       c
d       d
```

**DF2:**

```
id      documentType      documentUrl
a       3D                https://...a.dxf
a       Image             https://...a.jpg
b       PDF               https://...b.pdf
b       Image             https://...b.jpg
b       Image             https://...b2.jpg
c       PDF               https://...c.pdf
```

I want to create a column "image1" in DF1 and assign value based on below condition.

1. Check if `DF1['id']` value is available in `DF2['id']` and DF2['documentType'] == 'Image'
2. If so, assign `DF1['image1']` with the value in `DF2['documentUrl']` first occurring
3. If not, assign `DF1['image1']` a placeholder URL 'https://...no_image.jpg'

**So output should look like:**

```
id      product      image1
a       a            https://...a.jpg
b       b            https://...b.jpg
c       c            https://...no_image.jpg
d       d            https://...no_image.jpg
```

***Not sure how to solve this, but some thoughts:***

*-  join / merge was my first idea but how to handle the conditions?*

*-  maybe map / apply with a function that check the conditions*

```
DF1['image1'] = DF1['id'].map(DF2.set_index('id')['documentUrl'], condition)
```

Comment: this will do the filtering for you `df2[df2['id'].isin(df1['id']) & df2['type']=='image']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter first:

```
s = (DF2.loc[DF2.documentType=='Image']
        .drop_duplicates('id')
        .set_index('id')['documentUrl']
    )
DF1['image'] = DF1['id'].map(s)
```

Output:

```
  id product             image
0  a       a  https://...a.jpg
1  b       b  https://...b.jpg
2  c       c               NaN
3  d       d               NaN
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me - To avoid the NaN values and set a custom no image url I chained your solution with .fillna()

`DF1['image'] = DF1['id'].map(s).fillna('https://...no_image.jpg')`